# Overriding an async void event handler method from base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, async-await

I am not sure how to handle a following scenario. There is an interface that defines an event handling method 'OnSomethinHappening()'.

There is a base class that implements this as a virtual method and uses some async code in it.

There is a derived class that wants to override the virtual method, but also call the `base.OnSomethingHappening()`.

```
 public interface ISomething
    {
        void OnSomethingHappening();
    }

    public class BaseClass
    {
        public virtual async void OnSomethingHappening()
        {
            await Task.Delay(1999);
        }
    }

    public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        public override void OnSomethingHappening()
        {
            base.OnSomethingHappening();
            //some more code
        }
    }
```

**The problem is**, I cannot mark the method invocation as awaitable, since it returns void. It is fine to have async void methods for event handlers, so it cannot be changed to a Task (it ain't my code either).

So, how should I make sure that my derived class executes the `base.OnSomethingHappening()` properly before going to own code?

Does this solution make sense in the derived class?:

```
public override async void OnSomethingHappening()
        {
           await Task.Run(()=> base.OnSomethingHappening());
            //some more code
        }
```

Comment: I also have the same issue. @Stephen Cleary can you help out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So, how should I make sure that my derived class executes the base.OnSomethingHappening() properly before going to own code?

You don't.  That's why `async void` methods should be avoided.  They provide no possible way for the caller to know when the operation has completed, whether it completed successfully, or what the errors were, if there were any.  If you want to be able to ensure that the caller is able to know that information about the method, it needs to return a `Task`, not `void`.

Comment: Right, but isn't `async void` an established pattern for event handlers? In any case, this is not my code, but a rather well established framework (Prism) that has this and I have to cope with it...

Comment: @Bartosz `async void` is an established pattern for an asynchronous operation in which the caller has no interest in knowing when the operation completes, and whether it was successful or why it wasn't.  An event handler is a common situation where that situation exists, but not *all* event handlers are in that situation, just as not all situations where you don't care about when the operation ends are event handlers.  If you want to know when the method ends, it needs to return a `Task`, that's just inherent to `async` methods.

Comment: It's also unusual to override an event handler or wait for it to complete. Usually, event handlers will run independently of each other.